# Adminhtml grid does not display

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

I am trying to get a custom grid in an adminhtml module to display. I have tried many things, but cannot get it to work. Here are my files. The page loads, but it is a blank page.

**app/design/adminhtml/hewa/newdesign/layout/customer.xml**

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_customer_messages_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="hwadminhtml/customer_messages" name="messages.list">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_customer_messages_index>
</layout>
```

**app/code/local/Hwareh/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml**

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <customer translate="title" module="customer">
            <children>
                <messages translate="title" module="customer">
                    <title>Customer Messages</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/customer_messages/</action>
                    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                </messages>
            </children>
        </customer>
    </menu>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Hwareh/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml**

```
<customer_messages>Hwareh_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Messages</customer_messages>
<customer_messages_grid>Hwareh_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Messages_Grid</customer_messages_grid>
```

**app/code/local/Hwareh/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/MessagesController.php**

```
class Hwareh_Adminhtml_Customer_MessagesController extends     Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
protected $_publicActions = array('edit');

protected function _construct()
{
    $this->setUsedModuleName('Mage_Customer');
}

protected function _initAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
    ->_setActiveMenu('customer/messages')
    ->_addBreadcrumb($this->__('Customer'), $this->__('Customer'))
    ->_addBreadcrumb($this->__('Customer Messages'),$this->__('Customer Messages'));
    return $this;
}


public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_title($this->__('Customer'))
        ->_title($this->__('Customer Messages'));
    $this->_initAction()
        ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_messages')->toHtml)
        ->renderLayout();
}


public function gridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_messages_grid')->toHtml()
    );
}

//are the next two functions even needed?
public function exportInchooCsvAction()
{
    $fileName = 'customer_messages.csv';
    $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_messages_grid');
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
}

public function exportInchooExcelAction()
{
    $fileName = 'customer_messages.xml';
    $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_messages_grid');
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getExcelFile($fileName));
    }
}
?>
```

**app/code/local/Hwareh/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Messages.php**

```
class Hwareh_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Messages extends     Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_blockGroup = 'adminhtml';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml/customer_messages';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Messages');

    parent::__construct();
    $this->_removeButton('add');
    //$this->setTemplate('customer/messages.phtml');
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Hwareh/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Messages/Grid.php**

```
class Hwareh_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Messages_Grid extends     Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('customer_messages_grid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('desc');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('hwcustomer/messages')->getCollection();

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $helper = Mage::helper('customer');
    $currency = (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE);

    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Message Id#'),
        'index'  => 'entity_id'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('subject', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Subject'),
        'type'   => 'text',
        'index'  => 'subject'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('reply', array(
        'header'       => $helper->__('Replies'),
        'index'        => 'reply',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('status', array(
        'header'       => $helper->__('Status'),
        'index'        => 'status',
    ));


    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportInchooCsv', $helper->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportInchooExcel', $helper->__('Excel XML'));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that all your etc/config.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have already got complete `etc/config.xml`.

**Important**

I wouldn't name my module as `Adminhtml`, since it is used by magento core. I would name it something different.

Now,

This class needs to extend from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container` and constructor should be like this:

```
class Hwareh_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Messages extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container //Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_blockGroup = 'adminhtml';
    $this->_controller = 'customer_messages'; //changed check below
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Messages');

    parent::__construct();
    $this->_removeButton('add');
    //$this->setTemplate('customer/messages.phtml');
    }
}
```

Above settings are used in the parents _prepareLayout() method as below.

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setChild( 
        'grid',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
        $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

So this line

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
        $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
```

ends up to this

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_messages_grid');
```

That means it is calling your grid class `Hwareh_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Messages_Grid`

Comment: Cheers, you check my updated answer for more understanding of grid.

Comment: Yes, it is related to `_prepareLayout()` function, I would suggest to change  module name `adminhtml` to something else. `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_messages_grid')` is not getting called. How is your full config?

Comment: I have fixed it. In my config, the line `<customer_messages>Hwareh_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Messages</customer_messages>`
was `<customer_messages>Hwareh_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Messages</customer_messages>>`